# Duplicate Columns Error in Dynamic DataTable

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, loops, if-statement, for-loop

I have a problem in looping. My arrays are

```
 Dim sec As String() = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", _
                            "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "A2", "B2", "C2", "D2", "E2", "F2", "G2", "H2", "I2", "J2", "K2", "L2", _
                            "M2", "N2", "O2", "P2", "Q2", "R2", "S2", "T2", "U2", "V2", "W2", "X2", "Y2", "Z2"}
    Dim coys As String() = {"(COY = 'A' OR COY = 'B')", "(COY = 'C' OR COY = 'D')", "(COY = 'E' OR COY = 'F')", "(COY = 'G' OR COY = 'H')"}
```

And here is my code for the loop.

```
For x As Integer = 0 To coys.Length - 1
                cn.Open()
                'some codes
                cn.Close()
                For i As Integer = 0 To numsec2.SelectedValue - 1
                    Dim vHeader As String = sec(i)
                    If Not dt.Columns.Contains(vHeader) Then
                        Dim f As New Data.DataColumn(vHeader, GetType(System.String))
                        dt.Columns.Add(f)
                        f.AllowDBNull = True
                    ElseIf dt.Columns.Contains(vHeader) Then
                        Dim cc As New Data.DataColumn(vHeader, GetType(System.String))
                        dt.Columns.Add(cc)
                        cc.AllowDBNull = True
                    End If
                Next
            Next
```

What I want to happen is when run this loop it shall suppose to look like this
for example the coys length is 4
and the numsec.selected value is 2 which means it'll create 2 sections per 1 coy.

coy a contains rows of data's that has coy a on it. Many data in coy A.

Name | Coy | A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H |

John | A

Kold | B

Mike | C

Loki | D

Dezu | E

Math | F

Loop | G

Tane | H

When I try to run my code above it shows this error

[image]

Comment: The two branches of your `If` are identical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My program now works with this code

```
For i As Integer = 0 To numsec - 1
                Dim vHeader As String = sec(i)
                Dim asas As String = coys(x)
                If dt.Columns.Contains(vHeader & "_" & asas) Then
                    Dim f As New Data.DataColumn(vHeader & "_" & asas, GetType(System.String))
                    dt.Columns.Add(f)
                    f.AllowDBNull = True
                ElseIf Not dt.Columns.Contains(vHeader & "_" & asas) Then
                    Dim f As New Data.DataColumn(vHeader & "_" & asas, GetType(System.String))
                    dt.Columns.Add(f)
                    f.AllowDBNull = True
                End If
            Next
```

Answer (score 2):

In neither branch of the loop are you actually adding any data; you're just adding a column either way, redundantly half the time. Fix those two problems and see if the question remains.

Comment: I change it to this but still, if i select numsec value for exapamle 2, it only creates two section not eight 

For i As Integer = 0 To numsec2.SelectedValue - 1
                Dim vHeader As String = sec(i)
                If Not dt.Columns.Contains(vHeader) Then
                    Dim f As New Data.DataColumn(vHeader, GetType(System.String))
                    dt.Columns.Add(f)
                    f.AllowDBNull = True
                End If
            Next

Comment: @zref, why aren't you using sec.Length for the For loop?

Comment: If I used sec instead of numsec, It'll create a dynamic table with all of data in the array sec. Sec's are dynamic.